# Issue on executing Azure Datawarehouse stored procedure from Java

Tags: java, azure

I am getting error -

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unsupported parameter
>   type found while parsing RPC request. The request has been terminated.
>   when calling Azure Datawarehouse SP from Java.My Procedure  CREATE
>   PROC [dbo].[MyPROCEDURE] @param1 varchar,@param2 
>   varchar,@param3 nvarchar OUT,@param4 nvarchar
>   OUT,@param5 nvarchar

and I am invoking from java like :

```
callableStatement.setNString(1, "test");
callableStatement.setNString(2, "NA");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR);
```

Comment: Could you try to use `VARCHAR` or `LONGNVARCHAR`? Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes I have tried that too . I have tired multiple types. What I found , It is accepting the OUT param type only as INTEGER. Other types it is not accepting .

Comment: Are you passing a string length that is greater than the maximum on Azure SQL Warehouse?  NVARCHAR has a 4,000 character limit.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for pointing out this issue, I would like to confirm that it's a known issue within the engine of SQL Datawarehouse, as per the observation there is not much of viable workaround that we can propose at this point in time apart from what we already know of, and this issue is being worked on by our product team, I will keep monitoring the status of this known issue. Should you have any concerns, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Thanks Ming Xu for your response .

Comment: Is this issue resolved now ? Because i am getting the same error while calling a DWH stored procedure through c# code.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer